# can you explain what does % do here?

Tags: python

```
loop_condition = True

while loop_condition:
    print("Loop Condition keeps: %s" %(loop_condition))
    loop_condition = False
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation at all?  This is string formatting, like printf in C.  When you have `string % item` or  `string % tuple`, each element on the right side is substituted for any % items in the string.  In this case, %s asks that it be printed as a string, so this will print "Loop Condition keeps: True" and then "Loop Condition keeps: False".

Comment: loop_condition = False

while loop_condition:
    print("Loop Condition keeps: %s" %(loop_condition))
    loop_condition = True   ..... after replacing true and false .. why the output is not showing anything bro? can you please explain it?

Comment: Your `while` loop only runs if `loop_condition` is True.  If you set `loop_condition` to False, then the loop will not run at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `%s` will be replaced by the variable `loop_condition` within the string. The "s" means that the variable is formated as a string